# Custom field validation error in ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, .net-5

I somewhat can't wrap my head around it.

Lets assume simplest model possible:

```cs
public class Model
{
   [Required]
   [MaxLength(128)]
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

If you now use it in form and declare validation, it will work. But default messages are not the most pleasant for average user (Field must be an array of length X etc).

And now comes my question, how to create custom validation error? I have seen one useful topic that I can't find anymore, but they were overriding some function and there was no info provided how to call it.

I'm mostly interested in `MaxLength`, because for `Required` you can just set `Display`, which won't work for `MaxLength`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to change the default message try it with

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "YourCustomMessageString")]
public string Name {get;set;}
```